# defining operations on distributions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I'm currently learning distributions. My current intuition is that a distribution is a kind of weak limit in the space of linear functionals $C_c^\infty(U) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ of ordinary functions.

Is this a good intuition? The thing is that when we define certain operations with distributions, for example

- multiplication of two distributions with disjoint singular support
- convolution of two distributions

the operation might not actually commute with weak convergence of sequences in $\mathcal D'$.

For example, let $u$ be the distribution taking $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ to $\phi'(0)$. Then note $\langle u, 0\rangle \ne \lim_n\langle u, \sin (nx)\rangle$, as the limit on the right does not exist.

I'm just wondering if there's any way I should think about this. Sorry, I know it's vague.

Comment: Why weak limit? A distribution is a linear functional on test functions. And one should not take limits of test functions, test functions are what replaces the variable $x$ in $u(x)$ in some sense. Like a blurry variable. And $\sin(nx)$ is not in $C^\infty_c$ here anyway ...

Comment: I wanted to say "lot of arguments with distributions are sort of limiting arguments". I guess the limit doesn't need to be of test functions- $C^\infty$ or $C^1$ or even $L_{loc}^1$ functions will also work. Every distribution is such a limit because of the result saying that every distribution is a weak limit of a sequence of $C_c^\infty$ functions.

Comment: This doesn't change the fact that in your post you are doing a limit of test functions, and that they are not in $C^\infty_c$

Comment: Oh wait you're right, not sure what I was saying.. thanks